# Amazon Kinesis KCL client for Consumer not working in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

please help. I am having problems setting up the Consumer for Kinesis data stream in .NET console application.

I have done everything according to the documentation, but I still get a blank console screen whenever I run the consumer. The producer works fine so far and the AWS credentials are working.

1. I have JDK on my system all well configured (not new to Java development)
2. I have all the necessary policies attached to my IAM user
3. I can see that the producer can programmatically create streams, desc streams etc with the same AWS credentials

I can hit the breakpoint in Program when creating the KclProcess but I cannot hit any breakpoint inside the KinesisTest class below

As for the consumer, I've created a class Program.cs like below:

```
class Program  
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //added these lines after trying everything
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "***");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "***");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION", "us-east-1");

        try
        {
            KclProcess.Create(new KinesisTest()).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

and another class

```
public class KinesisTest: IRecordProcessor
{

    private static readonly TimeSpan Backoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    private static readonly TimeSpan CheckpointInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    private static readonly int NumRetries = 10;

    /// <value>The shard ID on which this record processor is working.</value>
    private string _kinesisShardId;

    private DateTime _nextCheckpointTime = DateTime.UtcNow;


    public void Initialize(InitializationInput input)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Initializing record processor for shard: " + input.ShardId);
        this._kinesisShardId = input.ShardId;
    }

    public void ProcessRecords(ProcessRecordsInput input)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Processing " + input.Records.Count + " records from " + _kinesisShardId);
        ProcessRecordsWithRetries(input.Records);

        // Checkpoint once every checkpoint interval.
        if (DateTime.UtcNow >= _nextCheckpointTime)
        {
            Checkpoint(input.Checkpointer);
            _nextCheckpointTime = DateTime.UtcNow + CheckpointInterval;
        }
    }

    public void Shutdown(ShutdownInput input)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Shutting down record processor for shard: " + _kinesisShardId);
        // Checkpoint after reaching end of shard, so we can start processing data from child shards.
        if (input.Reason == ShutdownReason.TERMINATE)
        {
            Checkpoint(input.Checkpointer);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessRecordsWithRetries(List<Record> records)
    {
        foreach (Record rec in records)
        {
            bool processedSuccessfully = false;
            string data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < NumRetries; ++i)
            {
                try
                {
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rec.Data);

                    Console.Error.WriteLine( String.Format("Retrieved record:\n\tpartition key = {0},\n\tsequence number = {1},\n\tdata = {2}", rec.PartitionKey, rec.SequenceNumber, data));

                    // Your own logic to process a record goes here.

                    processedSuccessfully = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Exception processing record data: " + data, e);
                }

                //Back off before retrying upon an exception.
                Thread.Sleep(Backoff);
            }

            if (!processedSuccessfully)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Couldn't process record " + rec + ". Skipping the record.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void Checkpoint(Checkpointer checkpointer)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Checkpointing shard " + _kinesisShardId);

        checkpointer.Checkpoint(RetryingCheckpointErrorHandler.Create(NumRetries, Backoff));
    }
}
```

and lastly the kcl.properties file:

```
executableName = dotnet KinesisTest.dll

streamName = testStream

applicationName = KinesisTest

AWSCredentialsProvider = DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

processingLanguage = C#

initialPositionInStream = TRIM_HORIZON

regionName = us-east-1

maxRecords = 5000

idleTimeBetweenReadsInMillis = 1000

# failoverTimeMillis = 10000
# workerId =
# shardSyncIntervalMillis = 60000
# callProcessRecordsEvenForEmptyRecordList = false
# parentShardPollIntervalMillis = 10000
# cleanupLeasesUponShardCompletion = true
# taskBackoffTimeMillis = 500
# metricsBufferTimeMillis = 10000
# metricsMaxQueueSize = 10000
# validateSequenceNumberBeforeCheckpointing = true
# maxActiveThreads = 0
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I was expecting to see the Consumer processing the data from the stream but it's just an empty console

Comment: you found some solution? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: Hey, just saw this. So I never found a way to make that work. But I did find a better way of processing the events in the stream

Answer (score 0):

While I never found an answer  to this question, I found a better and proper way to do this using lambdas.

My final setup involved using SNS to get the messages/events from Kinesis and then fanning out the message to any subscribers (In my case, SQS queues) which then provide the queued messages to lambdas.

Something like this:

```
                             SQS Queue ----------------> Lambda
                             ^
                            /
                           /
                          /
KINESIS STREAM ------->SNS-------->SQS Queue ------> Lambda
                          \
                           \
                            \
                             >SQS Queue ----------------> Lambda
```

You might ask why not Kinesis to SQS directly? or why not SNS to Lambda directly?

> First question's answer is that Kinesis isn't build for multiple
>   reads. SNS allows you to read once and fan it out to as many
>   subscribers as you need. If you have say 20 listeners who are waiting
>   to act on an event, you can't plug them all into Kinesis. So go SNS.
>
> Second question's answer is that SNS sometimes can lose messages and
>   not deliver or trigger the lambdas (very true). However (speculated
>   based on experience) this probability reduces if you connect it to
>   SQS, it almost always lands in the queue. The queues can then trigger
>   the lambdas.. They have only one job anyway.

So I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this by Bootstrap project. Bootstrap project run Java program which run your project. You can find ready Bootstrap project in KCL for .NET repo.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net/tree/master/Bootstrap

Perhaps you will have to do some changes in this project like a set "pom.xml" location or something else but you can debug this project to find out if everything started correctly.